# What is the probability that a series of $n$ throws of a fair die is not biased?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose you throw a regular and perfectly fair six-sided die $n$ times ($n\geq6$) to obtain a series of random numbers. What is the probability that the series is not biased at all, i.e., that the frequency of every number in the series is exactly $\frac{1}{6}$?

This question came up when I was thinking about an example to illustrate why 'p-hacking' is bad. But I don't know how to calculate the answer to the question. The only thing I believe to know is that this probability approaches $1$ as $n$ goes towards infinity, by the Law of the Large Numbers.

Comment: If $n$ is not a multiple of $6$ then the probability is $0$.  Otherwise it is $\dfrac{n!}{\big(\left(n/6\right)!\big)^6 6^n}$.  But it is the die which is supposed to be unbiased, not the sample

Comment: And the probability approaches $0$ as $n$ increases: for $n=6$ it is about $0.015432$ while for $n=60$ it is about $0.00007456$.  Something similar would happen with tossing a fair coin: the probability of exact equality goes down as the number of tosses increases, though the probability of being close to equality goes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the probability that every die face appears equally when you roll $6n$ dice (note I am assuming the number of dice is always a multiple of $6$, so each face appearing equally is possible). Basic combinatorics shows that
$$
p_n=\frac{(6n!)}{(n!)^6\cdot 6^{6n}}
$$
Let us look how $p_n$ changes as $n$ increases. Using Stirlings approximation, we find
$$
p_n\approx \frac{(6n)^{6n}e^{-6n}\sqrt{2\pi (6n)}}{(n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n})^66^{6n}}=Cn^{-5/2}
$$
where $C=\sqrt{6}/(2\pi)^{5}$ is a constant. Importantly, we see that $\lim_{n\to \infty }p_n=0$, and more specifically, that the rate at which the probability of an unbiased sample goes to zero is faster than quadratic. To put this in perspective, let us look at a relatively small instance of $p_n$. When you roll $12$ dice, the probability that every face appear twice is only
$$
\frac{12!}{2^6 \cdot 6^{12}}\approx 0.0034,
$$
This is a less than $1\%$ chance, and it quickly gets worse as $n$ increases. All of this illustrates the following important maxim to add to your intuition:

> The expected value is **not** the value you expect.

That is, while it is true that on average each face will appear on $n$ times when $6n$ dice are rolled, it is far from typical for this to actually happen all at once. The maxim applies very widely; if you flip $1000$ coins, while the expected number of heads is $500$, there is only a $2.5\%$ chance that the number of heads is exactly $500$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture in the end is not true. In fact, it is the opposite. The law of large number says that the share of e.g. ones will approach 1/6 as n goes to infinity. This does not mean that the number of each outcome will be the same, which must be true for the shares to be exactly 1/6. The probability of getting exacly the same number of each outcome will instead approach 0 as n increases indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks! I stand corrected and have to ponder about that difference a bit before I can understand it. It is counter-intuitive. Would you mind adding Henry's comment to your answer? It would be nice to have a definite answer to the question (including your correction). Or maybe someone else can do that.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I don't know how to add Henry's comment to my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll wait for more answers and if there are none will answer myself later with proper credits to you and Henry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the credit is all Henrys. i saw that he already made my point in a comment while I wrote my answer.